# Android DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog not rendering preview

Tags: android

I'm creating a form that consists of EditTexts which launch DatePickerDialogs and TimePickerDialogs.

Here are the sections of the code:

> DatePickerDialog

```
 DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

      @Override
      public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int chosenYear, int chosenMonth, int chosenDate) {

           year = chosenYear;
           month = chosenMonth;
           date = chosenDate;

           set(year, month, date);
      }
 }, year, month, date);

 datePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
 datePicker.show();
```

> TimePickerDialog

```
 TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

      @Override
      public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int chosenHour, int chosenMinute) {
           hour = chosenHour;
           minute = chosenMinute;

           set(hour, minute);
       }
 }, hour, minute, false);

 timePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
 timePicker.show();
```

Everything works as it should be such as launching the dialogs and setting the date properly. There's this one problem. The previews are not rendered. I don't know why. Hope someone could help. Thanks.

Here are the screenshots:
Notice the white backgrounds.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your styles.xml add two new styles:

```
<style name="DatePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
<style name="TimePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Then refer to these styles in your custom theme as followed:

```
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme" tools:targetApi="21">@style/DatePicker</item>
<item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme" tools:targetApi="21">@style/TimePicker</item>
```